# Can Linux span across VGA + DVI-P + HDMI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The new motherboard I purchased supports three video output ports: standard VGA, DVI-P and HDMI.

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on the machine. I have tried connecting DVI-P and HDMI at the same time and this seems to work.

If I connect all three ports to three different monitors, will it still work? Can I actually move my mouse across all three monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if all three are actually independent. If the video card only has two real outputs then only two (unique) displays will ever work on it.

Comment: More specifically yet, some mainboards have graphic chips allowing you to control output ports independently or shared. I have come across a mainboard (one graphic chip only) that had D-sub/VGA and DVI ports, and xrandr showed VGA, LVDS and DVI. One of the these three xrandr displays was a multiplex controlling both the D-sub and DVI ports.